# C++ and STL: Constructor Factory

Tags: c++, factory, functor

I have a big factory, and I'm trying to figure out how to make it look pretty.
There are about 40 possible object/constructor combinations:

```
if(algorithm == "SHA-1")
    return new HashImpl<...>(algorithm, seed, size);
if(algorithm == "SHA-224")
    return new HashImpl<...>(algorithm, seed, size);
if(algorithm == "SHA-256")
    return new HashImpl<...>(algorithm, seed, size);
... 
if(algorithm == "AES" || algorithm == "AES128")
    return new BlockCipherImpl<...>(algorithm, seed, size);  
...
if(algorithm == "HmacSHA1")
    return new HmacImpl<...>(algorithm, seed, size);
...
```

Is there a way to put this into a map so I can at least do away with the sequential search? I'm having problems figuring out how to make the constructor a functor.

EDIT: The code can be found here:
http://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-cplusplus/source/browse/trunk/src/crypto/SecureRandomImpl.cpp, starting around line 130.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what goes into the <...> of the HashImpl?

Comment: Your code doesn't show a difference in what's returned. What's different for a different `algorithm` string ? The template arguments ? The constructor arguments ? Which ones ?

Comment: Robert and Sander - My bad. I posted a link to the actual code. All return a 'BaseImplementation*'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to use them fancy newfangled maps.

```
template <class Impl>
BaseImplementation* makeAlgo (const std::string& algo, 
                                const byte* seed, size_t size)
{
    return new Impl(algo, seed, size);
}

typedef BaseImplementation* makeAlgo_t (const std::string& algo, 
                                          const byte* seed, size_t size);

typedef struct { std::string name; makeAlgo_t func; } NamedAlgoMaker_t;


NamedAlgoMaker_t factory[] = {
  { "SHA-1",     makeAlgo< HashImpl <...> >  },
  ...
  { "HmacSHA1",  makeAlgo< HmacImpl <...> > },
  ...
};
```

If you keep the array sorted, you can use binary search to find the algorithm quickly.

Of course you can build a map (or hash/unordered map) out of these things too, if you want to.

Comment: @n.m.: Not as pretty as I hoped, but I can blame you for ugly C++ syntax :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use either a map of lambda functions perhaps

Answer (score 0):

So it will still be visually ugly. But you can make it faster in the following way:

1. Create ~40 factory methods, each of which returns one of these choices.
2. Create a map where fnPointerTypedef is the return type of your factory method.
3. Do a dictionary look up, and return the result of whichever function you look up.
4. <s>Create an enum that gives a number for each option (e.g. SHA-1 = 0, SHA-224 = 1, etc..).</s>
5. <s>Create a map that maps the string name to the {int|enum}.</s>
6. <s>Create an array of function pointers, and have each spot in the array point to the correct corresponding factory method.</s>
7. <s>Do a dictionary look up and return functionArray[enumInt];</s>

(Edit: Thanks n.m. for more direct implementation)

Comment: Hopefully if you're going to do it this way, you know how to do Vim macros or something similar

Comment: There's no need to map from string to int and then from int to function pointer. A direct mapping from string to function pointer will do.